# What is the radius of the convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty} n^{3} \cdot x^{n}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I assume that I should use the root test which gives, that $n^2 \cdot |x|$ how can I continue it?

Comment: The ratio test will work as well.

Comment: Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.

Answer (score 4):

With root test, you will have $n^{3/n}|x|\rightarrow|x|$. We now let $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think $n^2$ should be there.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |n^\frac{3}{n} x|=|x|<1$$

Answer (score 0):

By the action of the forward difference operator,
$$ (1-x)^4 \sum_{n\geq 1} n^3 x^n $$
is a polynomial, hence the radius of convergence is one.